# Access HttpContext in TelemetryInitializer in Azure Function with ServiceBusTrigger

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to enrich my dependency telemetry with validation errors from an external web service I call based on messages I receive from a service bus trigger.

What I tried was to add the `HttpContextAccessor` in my `Startup` class like so:

```
public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
        builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, BadRequestReasonTelemetryInitializer();
    }
}
```

And then utilize it in my telemetry initializer like so:

```
public class BadRequestReasonTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public BadRequestReasonTelemetryInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (telemetry is DependencyTelemetry req)
        {
            if (req.ResultCode == "400")
            {
                // toggle re-use
                _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind();

                var stream = new StreamReader(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Body);
                var body = stream.ReadToEnd();

                // reset stream to preserve data
                _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
                req.Properties.Add("Reason", body);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that the `HttpContext` is always null. Which I think makes sense because I have a function with a `ServiceBusTrigger`. But the question is how can I get the current http context from the external web service call? Is there a way to grab it from `DependencyTelemetry` somehow? I'm targeting .NET Core 2.1 and function runtime v2.

EDIT (Add call for clarity):

```
using (var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient())
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
    using (var result = await httpClient.PostAsync($"{BaseUrl}/endpoint", payload))
    {
        // if the result is 400 I would like this to go to AI through the initializer
    }
}
```

Comment: You will never be able to grab the HttpContext from the external web service. The Azure Function instance is running in a whole other process on a different machine. What information do you need from the context?

Comment: I see. I was hoping to get the validation errors from the response body and append those to the telemetry as a custom property.

Comment: Actually, @PeterBons could you elaborate a little bit on that comment? I think we may have misunderstood each other due to the way I wrote the sentence in my original question. I've added some of the code from the call I'm making within the actual function. It is the response body from that call I would like to add to the telemetry as a property.